# Custom UserControl with Dependency Properties Not Updating on UI?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have made the following sample user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DLSAdministration.Controls.CombinedTextBoxControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="30"
         d:DesignWidth="250"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BGBrush" Color="#3A3A3A" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="#656565" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=tb}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=tb}">
    <TextBox Name="tb"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Background="{StaticResource BGBrush}"
             BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}"
             BorderThickness="2"
             FontFamily="Calibri"
             FontSize="16"
             Foreground="Snow">
        Content
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,5"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               FontStyle="Italic"
               Foreground="Red"
               Padding="2">
        Label
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

With the code behind file:

```
    public partial class CombinedTextBoxControl : UserControl
{
    public CombinedTextBoxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // the exposed instance public properties.
    public string TextboxText
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextboxTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextboxTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public string TextBlockText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextBlockTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBlockTextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextboxTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "TextboxText",
                typeof (string),
                typeof (CombinedTextBoxControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("TextboxText")
            );

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextBlockTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "TextBlockText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(CombinedTextBoxControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("TextBlockText ")
            );
}
```

My UserControl is consumed like this:

```
        <my:CombinedTextBoxControl x:Name="combinedTextBoxControl1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Width="182"
                               Margin="77,76,0,0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               TextBlockText="Name"
                               TextboxText="Ibrar Mumtaz" />
```

I have not even bound any data to this control and ***I can't even get it to display some sample data I provided via xaml?*** Can you spot the mistake? I have looked around on SO and noticed the mistakes of others but I am not making any obvious mistakes though so I am completely stumped on this one .... : S

Comment: Pleas don't do stuff like that Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=tb}" Don't bind to another ones width, this completely destroys the purpose of the very nice layoutsystem of WPF. Besides in this case, it does absolutely nothing. Width is not something that is calculated, its something you can set to "suggest" WPF that you want this size.

Comment: I just realized what the problem is ... this is probably working but the each DP should introduce a property changed call back to update the content or text property each user control has natively that MightySoft have coded for you. Otherwise it's taking a value you give but then storing but you have not told it what do with it. YEP! I definitely know what the problem is :)

Comment: No you don't need any changed callback or whatever, just check my answer. And who is MightySoft?

Comment: @ dowhilefo? <-- Sorry I am a WPF newbie. So what are you suggesting ... change it to Auto?

Comment: Mightysoft = Microsoft <-- it's just a pun = )

Comment: No, read my answer below :) I just say that you don't use your dependency properties at all. You just have a textbox and textblock in your user control and both of them doesn't know about your two obviously intended properties. Just bind their text properties to your dependency properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect it to work? You have a dependency property in your CombinedTextBoxControl but you don't use it anywhere. You want to assign this property to your child controls inside your control template, this is a way to do it:

Give your usercontrol a name

```
         <UserControl x:Class="DLSAdministration.Controls.CombinedTextBoxControl" 
            x:Name="myControl"
```

and add a binding to your textbox and textblock like

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl, TextBlockText}"
```

Just another note: your layout is wrong. You have a grid with only one cell, and you place a textblock and a textbox in it, one is placed on the other. Try adding 2 ColumnDefinitions one for the label, one for the textbox and set the proper attached property on both controls (Grid.Column="0" on the textblock, Grid.Column="1" on the textbox).

Comment: Thank you - don't worry about the layout, it introduces a layered effect which is intentional. I do understand what you mean in your answer regarding layout.